# std::stable_sort not stable at all?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, c++11

I'm running into a bizarre bug when using `std::stable_sort` on a `Point` datatype. The default ordering of `Point` values is determined first by x-coordinate and then by y-coordinate to break ties. However, I'm using `std::stable_sort` to sort points based on their slopes relative to an external point. And I keep finding that `std::stable_sort` does not preserve the relative ordering of points with the same slope relative to the external point.

Here is code that executes correctly and yields the expected output.

```
std::vector<Point> points;
/* 
Work is done here to fill the vector with Points.
These Points form several horizontal lines. 
*/
std::sort(points.begin(), points.end()); //Sorts Points based on their coordinates
for (const Point& elem : points)  //Displays sorted vector
    std::cout << elem << ' ';

Output:
(1888, 7657) (2682, 14118) (4750, 4652) (5067, 14118) (5766, 4652) (7453, 14118) 
(7599, 7657) (7821, 14118) (8934, 7996) (9972, 4652) (10375, 12711) (10411, 7996) 
(12772, 7657) (13291, 7996) (13832, 7657) (14226, 12711) (16307, 4652) (18177, 12711) 
(20385, 12711) (20547, 7996) 
//The Points are sorted in order of increasing x-coordinate
```

But when I use `std::stable_sort` to sort the vector based on the slopes of all elements relative to the first one, the vector is no longer sorted in order of increasing x-coordinate even among points with the same slope.

```
const Point& P0 = points[0];
auto compLambda = [&](const Point& a, const Point& b)
    {return P0.slopeCompare(a,b) != 1;}
std::stable_sort(points.begin() + 1, points.end(), compLambda);
for (const Point& elem : points)
    std::cout << elem << ' ';

Output:
(1888, 7657) //First point remains unmoved, as expected
(4750, 4652) (5766, 4652) (9972, 4652) (16307, 4652)

/*These points all form a horizontal line with the first point.*/
(13832, 7657) (12772, 7657) (7599, 7657) 
/*However, they appear to be sorted in order of DECREASING x-coordinates!??!?*/

(20547, 7996) (13291, 7996) (10411, 7996) (8934, 7996) (20385, 12711) (18177, 12711) 
(14226, 12711) (10375, 12711) (7821, 14118) (7453, 14118) (5067, 14118) (2682, 14118)
```

In general, `std::stable_sort` seems to consistently, magically reverse the relative ordering of elements that compare to have the same slope. Other than that, the methods referenced above seem to work fine. I've posted the methods of the Point class below (other than `operator<<`), but I don't see how a bug in any of those should cause `std::stable_sort` to become unstable.

Here is a compressed version of the Point class.

```
#include <limits>

class Point{
private:
    int x, y;
public:
    ///Default constructor for Point[] arrays
    Point(void) = default;   

    ///Regular constructor
    Point(int x, int y): x(x), y(y) {}

    ///Default comparison operators
    inline bool operator<(const Point& other){
        return x < other.x || x == other.x && y < other.y;
    }
    inline bool operator>(const Point& other){
        return x > other.x || x == other.x && y > other.y;
    }
    inline bool operator==(const Point& other){
        return x == other.x && y == other.y;
    }

    ///Returns the slope between this point and another. Note that vertical   
    ///lines have a slope of INF and the method returns -INF if the argument 
    ///is the same as the instance. Also, horizontal lines are treated 
    ///specially to prevent evaluation of -0.0
    inline double slopeTo(const Point& other){
        if (x == other.x)
            return y == other.y ? -HUGE_VAL : HUGE_VAL;
        else if (y == other.y)
            return 0;
        else
            return static_cast<double>(y - other.y)/(x - other.x);
    }

    ///Slope comparator
    inline int slopeCompare(const Point& a, const Point& b){
        if (slopeTo(a) > slopeTo(b))
            return 1;
        else if (slopeTo(a) < slopeTo(b))
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of rounding of double, slopeTo is inherently unstable.  So slopeCompare is unstable so sort using it is at best unstable and possible worse than unstable.

You can get much better results by comparing slopes by cross multiplying, rather than dividing.  But for large values that still isn't perfect.

Edit: On first look I missed the more serious bug:

```
auto compLambda = [&](const Point& a, const Point& b)
    {return P0.slopeCompare(a,b) != 1;}
```

That returns true for a==b when it needs to return false.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the more serious bug in the original code until a minute before you posted the above comment.

Comment: @Navneeth you're assumption about doubles is incorrect - but more importantly, **you're not doing double division.  you're dividing integers**.

Comment: Lessons learned here for me: #1) Don't recreate code, just copy it. #2) Don't make replies without thorough inspection. It turns out the logic of compLambda was incorrect. I simply returned true if the elements weren't out of order. So this will be my accepted answer.. Any other typos, including my failure to use static_cast<double>(y - other.y)/(x - other.x), were not in the original code.

Answer (score 2):

Your comparison operator is invalid for `std::stable_sort` because it does not implement [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings).

```
inline bool operator<(const Point& other){
    return x < other.x || x == other.x && y == other.y;
}
```

With this logic, if 2 points `a` and `b` are the same, `a<b` will return `true` **and** `b<a` will also return `true`.

A valid comparison with strict weak ordering would be

```
inline bool operator<(const Point& other){
    return x < other.x || (x == other.x && y < other.y);
}
```

Comment: This was a typo. I've fixed it, but it doesn't seem to be the source of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In your `operator <` for

```
return x < other.x || x == other.x && y == other.y;
```

You need

```
return x < other.x || x == other.x && y < other.y;
```

Personally I'd put some more parentheses in too. Also you could save some typing by defining `operator >(a, b)` as `!(b < a)`.

Comment: That is a bug and it would have had symptoms if two of the points had the same x value.  But the testing described would never trigger that bug and it isn't the bug that the question asked about.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I've fixed that in the posted code. But my original code does not have that bug, (un)fortunately.

Comment: Defining `operator >(a, b)` as `!(b < a)` surely is a mistake. It would have to be `!(b <= a)`.

Comment: @PaulGroke We're both wrong. `a > b` is equivalent to `b < a` or `!(a <= b)`.

Comment: @Alan Stokes: Er. Yes :-) `!(a <= b)` of course. And of course only for stuff with no funky NULL/NaN logic (i.e. no floats).